# How to display images in my app after creating a Jar file?

Tags: java, swing, embedded-resource

I'm losing images of my project after creating a jar file, although they work just fine on eclipse

i have tried this code bellow to import an image to a Jbutton

```
valid = new javax.swing.JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("/resources/cashier-machine.png")).getImage())
             .getScaledInstance(170, 170, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

i'm still failing to get images after creating a Jar file for the project

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: `getScaledInstance(170, 170, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)` Rescale images before they are put into the Jar. It's faster and results in a better image (generally).